# How to stop storing AnyCancellable after Swift Combine Sink has received at least one value?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a sink that needs to be canceled as soon as I receive the first value. I don't care about future values, just the first one published. Because without storing the `AnyCancelable` created by the sink, the garbage collector will delete the sink, I must store it. At the same time, I must also clean it up after the sink has completed, otherwise, I will have a memory leak.

I built one using a UUID → AnyCancelable map, but I am worried that this is more complex than it should be; is there another way of doing this? What's recommended by Combine?

```
@Published var locationState: (location: CLLocation?, error: Error?)?
var requestLocationSinks: [String: AnyCancellable] = [:]

// 1. Generate ID to uniquely identify the current sink.
let sinkID = UUID().uuidString

// 2. Start the sink and store it in our ID → AnyCancellable dictionary.
requestLocationSinks[sinkID] = $locationState.sink { locationState in
    if let locationState = locationState {
        invokeCallbackWithLocationState(locationState)
    }
    // 3. Remove the stored AnyCancellable as soon as we received our first value!
    self.requestLocationSinks.removeValue(forKey: sinkID)
}
```

Comment: There is no garbage collector, but (automatic) reference counting. The operator `sink(...)` (presumably) returns a `Subscribers.Sink` type-erased as an `AnyCancellable`. If no one holds on to that return-value (by assigning or storing), the reference-count is not incremented (from 0) and the cancellable is released.

Comment: @FelixLieb If you don't keep a reference to the cancellable, the sink handler can (will) be disposed (released) before it had a chance to be executed. You know, like it says in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just need to keep it alive until the sink is called once, you can just create a temporary variable

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
cancellable = $locationState.sink { locationState in
    if let locationState = locationState {
        invokeCallbackWithLocationState(locationState)
    }
    cancellable = nil
}
```

This will retain the `AnyCancellable` long enough (because the closure retains the reference)

Comment: I was going for that too, but that (surprisingly) didn't work for me. EDIT: checked again with my code - it works now, not sure why it didn't before. +1

Comment: Btw, any thoughts on suppressing the warning, "Variable 'requestLocationSink' was written to, but never read"?

Comment: Change it to `if cancellable != nil { cancellable = nil }`

Comment: All this said, a more appropriate solution would be to encapsulate the individual combine requests in their own type with a member for the cancellable that'll then be automatically disposed once the parent type is disposed. Bit this is a good workaround for simple code.

Comment: Beware of this! Combine is probably, most of the time, used for asynchronous work. Though, if the work-item is not asynchronous, the closure is executed before the assignment, hence `var cancellable` will only have the subscription assigned after the closure was executed. You can replicate that in a playground using a Future which immediately calls the promise. If you dispatch the call to the promise, it will work as expected.

Comment: @FelixLieb that's irrelevant, as the `cancellable` variable in this example just served the purpose of retaining it for long enough so the closure is called. If the closure was synchronous, then it becomes a no-op

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, you might deem this irrelevant for the intention of "capturing the variable long enough". Though, the described situation leads to the variable having a value assigned afterwards, what might be unexpected and might be of relevance to someone else.

Comment: @FelixLieb you're clearly not understanding the part about how to do this in production...

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, why do I have the impression of being insulted with sarcasm. What do you think should I feel, if you tell me, that I "clearly do not understand..." I pointed out, that in certain circumstances, something could happen, that someone, writing it like that, might not have expected. I don't see, where it's wrong. I didn't even say: This answer is wrong. It's actually, what I'm doing myself. I just wanted to raise the awareness of the special case. No need to be angry about it.

Comment: No, you're writing incorrect comments all over this thread and ignoring the previous comments that _do_ point out how this is not production quality code.

Answer (score 4):

if you are only interested in the first element of the upstream you can use either the operator `.first()` or the operator `.prefix(1)`. They are equal. With `.prefix(n)` you can define the number of passed upstream elements.

```
myPublisher
     .first()
     .sink( ... )

or

myPublisher
     .prefix(1 or n)
     .sink( ... )
```

Please note, that the two operators above, cause an `.finished` completion. This means that the subscription will be deleted after the operation.

`publisher is triggered -> receiveValue -> receiveCompletion (finished) -> subscription is deleted`

If you work with `AnyCancellable` and want to delete your subscription, you should use the `.cancel()` function of the `AnyCancellable` .

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
cancellable = myPublisher
     .sink(receiveValue: { value in 
          // Your logic.
          cancellable.cancel()
     })
```

I suppose that in your case the operator `.first()` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Regardless if I am using `first()` or not, I still need to preserve the `AnyCancellable` returned by the `sink()` call and cancel it at the end yeh? So using first() is just a safer way of doing this?

Comment: @Zorayr 
You definitely have to cache the subscription in an `AnyCancellable`. Otherwise it is lost immediately and your publisher will be never triggered.

If you use `first()`, you have to store the subscription. BUT you don't have to cancel it, because this happens automatically. If you use `first()` and your publisher is triggered once, a `finished` completion is sent after that and this cancels the subscription! 

Completions cancel the subscriptions! After being triggered `receiveCompletion`, the subscription is automatically canceled and the publisher is no longer triggered!

Comment: I came here, searching for solutions to handling storage of subscriptions in long lived objects. I was searching for a way to manage the subscription-store and cleanup stored subscriptions, of finished publishers. The question seemed to have asked that, but the understanding of the matter seemed to be unclear as well.

Comment: @FelixLieb I didn't quite understand what you meant by your last sentence. But if you mean the storage of subscriptions, then either `AnyCancellable ` or `Set<AnyCancellable>` are available to you at Combine. 
Usage:
`let anyCancellable = myPublisher.sink(...)`
`myPublisher.sink(...).store(in: &self.anyCancellableSet)`

Comment: @dennis_ka, not sure, the comments are long enough to elaborate sufficiently :-) In a view, `anyCancellableSet` can commonly be expected to be "auto cleaned-up", when the view is "released". In long-lived objects, which live until the app is terminated, like a service or a manager, whatever we name these, we might need to store short-lived subscriptions, which then pile up in the set. So I was on the search for ideas on how to manage those "no longer needed, but still stored subscriptions".

Comment: @FelixLieb All clear. I had the same problem. Once I implemented a Combine-based communication stack, which was a singleton. Several services lived in it. I solved it by deleting the subscribers in the `deinit` method. But be careful! `deinit` is triggered only when the instance is about to be cleared from memory. If you have memory leaks somewhere in the app (the instance are not cleanly deleted from memory), then `deinit` is not triggered even at `instance = nil`. And with Combine, you can very quickly produce such memory leaks e.g. by using strong `self` in the `sink` closures.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the accepted answers do not work if your publisher is a `CurrentValueSubject`

You can test that the following code results in "cancellable is nil" being printed out.

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)

func main() {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    cancellable = publisher.sink { _ in
        if let cancellable {
            print("cancelled!")
            cancellable.cancel()
        } else {
            print("cancellable is nil")
        }
    }
}

main()
```

This is likely due to the fact that the publisher doesn't have to wait for the event, so execution of `sink` happens in a sync manner, before the cancellable variable is actually set.

Unfortunately, the only way to "fix" this is to force it to be async. Something like this works:

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)

func main() {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    cancellable = publisher.sink { _ in
        
        // -- NEW: Wrap the cancellation into an async block
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let cancellable {
                print("cancelled!")
                cancellable.cancel()
            } else {
                print("cancellable is nil")
            }
        }
    }
}

main()
```